# Could not connect to development server on android emulator and on real device

Tags: react-native

When I run "react-native run-android",it gives me error:"could not connect to development server...".-- The red screen

- OS: Windows 7
- node version:8.2.1
- npm version:4.1.2
- react-native version:0.47.1
- react-native-cli version:2.0.1
- android device and emulator version: 5.1.1

i followed following command:

- react-native init ProjectName
- cd ProjectName
- react-native run-android

And this makes the package server run automatically.
But I am not able to access the package server from browser on the machine and the mobile.

My android device connected to computer has debugging enabled i checked it using adb devices command.
Usb debug is on.

I tried running the project on real device and on emulator. On Both I got error: "Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle' Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a package server'.

reloading i get the error: "Could not connect to development server."

Then i set the host and port number on development setting on both and got the error "Could not connect to development server."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDBVt.jpg)

So how to fix the red error screen issue?Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post the error screen you are receiving on your device ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api/43277765#43277765

Comment: I have tried both but the thing is i am not able to access the development server from the browser of my system also.

Comment: What port number and ip you entered ?

Comment: I entered my system IP where development server is running and port which is visible when running react-native run-android command which is usually 8081.

Comment: @ShipraJain : Can you check if the emulator is connected to wifi and is on the same network as the development machine/server?

Comment: @Chirag: Emulator is on same network as the development server.

Comment: @ShipraJain did you try Expo IDE https://expo.io/ ? It makes it easier to develop and test React Native apps.

Comment: @ ArtemBaranovskii: Yes i tried Expo IDE and it is working for me but i THINK that it does not render the native control. I might be wrong here but my understanding says that only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to open this link in browser. It will automatically bundle the assets.

http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false

You development server should be running while running this command.

Comment: When i try running the command "react-native start". It prompts in the cmd that the "Running Packager on 8081". And when i try browsing the above link it shows me the error: "This site can’t be reached"

Comment: Run the command react-native start. After the development server is started successfully open this url in browser. Check if this solves your problem.

Comment: If packager is already running try killing it and start again. If packager is successfully started then the site can't be reached error will not come.

Comment: I tried that only. Still no luck. When i run the command react-native start it prompts for Running packager on port 8081; looking for JS FIles in folder; React Packager ready; Loading dependency graph, done. on the command prompt. But still it shows the site cannot be reached.

Comment: Try creating assets folder inside android/app/src/main/assets of your recat native project.Then try opening the url

Comment: Tried but no luck.

Comment: Please check if you have followed all the correct steps while setting up react native

Comment: All steps followed are rechecked still no luck.