# ReactRedux Fetch Network Request Failed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to fetch from localhost:

```
export function fetchUsersFromAPI() {
    return(dispatch) => {
        dispatch(getUsers())
         fetch('https://localhost:3000/users')
      // fetch('https://192.168.0.2:3000/users/')  //< same error for this too
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(json => dispatch(getUsersSuccess(json.results)))
        .catch(err => dispatch(getUsersFailure(err)))
    }
}
```

Accessing https://192.168.0.2:3000/users or https://localhost:3000/users from browser returns :

`[{"id":1,"name":"Name1","color":"Green"},{"id":2,"name":"Name2","color":"Red"},{"id":3,"name":"Name3","color":"Yellow"}]`

So its already in `json`. Is it mandatory to use `https` and not `http` in Redux fetch?

I passed the `err` to my reducer so I get :

```
"TypeError: Network request failed
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onerror (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:15946:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.dispatchEvent (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:18719:35)
    at XMLHttpRequest.setReadyState (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:18502:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.__didCompleteResponse (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:18358:14)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:18453:45
    at RCTDeviceEventEmitter.emit (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:9351:35)
    at MessageQueue.__callFunction (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:8235:42)
    at http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:8051:15
    at MessageQueue.__guard (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:8206:9)
    at MessageQueue.callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue (http://localhost:8081/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=true&minify=false:8050:13)"
```

What am I doing wrong? If I use `fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')` it works. Please help.

Comment: What is running on `3000`? do you have a proxy or is that another server?

Comment: It's my localhost. Node sever. I used OpenSSL to create the certs.

Comment: try catching the error with `fetch('https://localhost:3000/users').catch(e => console.log(e))`

Comment: try using 10.0.2.2:3000 instead of localhost:3000 for android

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal Same error. Network request failed.

Comment: ok. can you also check android's manifest file whether internet permission is there or not? I am assuming that you are running it on Android

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Android Emulator. If I change to `fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')`, it works. Problem on localhost.

Comment: Also, this line is present in the manifest file :     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in `\my03\android\app\src\main`

Comment: I think its would be helpful advice https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277765/8613805