# Call localhost API within react native ( android device : connected through local)

Tags: android, react-native, fetch, axios, firewall

Have created a simple GET API using node.js and trying to consume it within my expo-react native project using axios/fetch.

The GET API is called whenever user clicks on submit button.

Submit -> http://localhost:port/api

However, when I am trying to test the feature on my android device by connecting the device through datacable and selecting "local" connect type in expo, the API call always falls under exception.

When I tried to log the exception, the exception is printed empty.

I double checked the API and it works fine when tested through postman.

I tried replacing localhost url with my-Ip (http://IP:port/api) and also with 127.0.0.1/127.0.2.2 (http://127.0.0.1:port/api , http://127.0.2.2:port/api) , but nothing seems to make the API call a success.

When I replaced the localhost URL with Facebook's network sample API, the application worked just fine. So, there is no issue with the API calling method.

Also, tried adding the port to windows inbound firewall request but that didn't work too.

Can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 4):

You must call the API from your local IP address. To get your local IP, just do the following:

If you are on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
ifconfig | grep 192
```

If you are on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
ip -c a | grep 192
```

Your local IP address will probably be something like `192.168.0.XXX`.

Comment: Tried replacing localhost with my local IP,  but sadly didn't work.

Comment: Make sure your phone is connected to the same wi-fi as your computer. And check if the local IP is accessible from the same computer. Sometimes there are problems regard ports and firewall.

Comment: The phone and the laptop are connected to the same WiFi .Tried accessing http://myIp:port/api on my mobile browser, it seems to be unreachable too.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have got the wrong IP address. You should get the local IP address. What IP are you using to test?

Comment: Got the IP from windows 10 --> run --> Cmd --> ipconfig --> IP v4

Comment: For now ngrok is the way to go for me. Thanks vmf91 for sticking through.

Comment: Yes, with ngrok everything is working. Thanks for checking :).

Comment: ngrok Save my life in this problem!

Answer (score 3):

yes, i also had this problem until use my Local IP (example: http://192.168.1.55:port) instead 127.0.0.1
please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277765/4158479)

Comment: Tried replacing localhost with my local IP,  but sadly didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Good day,
This is working

I use my machine's IP the Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2: IPV4 Address

And allow my port on firewall both Inbound and outbound rules

[image]