# How to access localhost in react native expo with android emulator?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

first of all,
I need to access my api in localhost
I've tried everything but why it doesn't works (?)

first, I set my axios setup like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost/github/xxxx/index.php/api',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic username pass',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

but doesn't work,

Then I try this :

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://192.xxx.xx.142/github/xxxx/index.php/api',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic username pass',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

the baseURL is from IPv4 Address in ipconfig/all

but doesn't work, Then I've read about android emulator
they said " if u want to use localhost then u need to set url to **10.0.2.2**
like this :

```
import axios from 'axios';

    export default axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://10.0.2.2/github/xxxx/index.php/api',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic username pass',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    });
```

but still not working :(

and the error of message always like this :
" Error while reading multipart response "

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUNiK.png)

how to fix this ? :(

I'm building the api using rest_api plugin codeigniter

thank you before

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277765/9009196 number 2 worked for me

Answer (score 0):

> Look like duplicate with : [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)

There is a "LAN" option to set on Expo.

Comment: @KaretNasiPadang so, could you provide more information about your setup ? Android / iOS and if you used a guide ?

According to the other post, there is many things to check : https://stackoverflow.com/a/54105349/5470616

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by my self,
after I search for the problem, the problem is you need setting localhost to static
in apache ( httpd.conf ) , you need to add manualy your your local IP to there with port

Answer (score 0):

Try using adb reverse tcp:{port_number} tcp:{port_number}

This will route the request from emulators