# React native code is unable to send data to django api

Tags: javascript, django, react-native

I am a beginner and I'm using Django in the backend of my react native app. I am unable to add data to the django admin panel from my app using fetch method. I am not getting any errors but my data is not getting posted to the backend.I have used the django api as the url in fetch method.
Please let me know if any other code snippet is required to check.
Would appreciate some help here.

```
export class LoginScreen extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      name: '',
    };
  }

  updateValue(text, field) {
    if (field == 'email') {
      this.setState({
        email: text,
      });
    } else if (field == 'pwd') {
      this.setState({
        pwd: text,
      });
    }
  }

  submit() {
    let collection = {};

    collection.email = this.state.email;
    collection.pwd = this.state.pwd;
    console.warn(collection);
    let url='http://10.0.0.2:8000/api/mdlApp/'



    fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(collection),
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((collection) => {
        console.log('Success:', collection);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('../images/bg4.png')} style={styles.bg}>
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
          <Logo />
          <View style={styles.container1}>
            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputBox}
              name="email"
              placeholder="Enter Your Email"
              placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'email')}
            />

            <TextInput
              style={styles.inputBox}
              name="pwd"
              placeholder="Enter Your Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              placeholderTextColor="#ffffff"
              onChangeText={(text) => this.updateValue(text, 'pwd')}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity
              //onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeApp')}
              onPress={() => this.submit()}
              style={styles.button}
              htmlType="submit">
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}> LOGIN </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.signupTextCont}>
            <Text style={styles.signupText}>Don't have an account yet?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Register')}
              style={styles.signupButton}>
              <Text>Register Now</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Does API work when u test it in Postman?

Comment: Yes it does work in Postman. @OliverD

Comment: You tested on Android?

Comment: Yes I did test it on android emulator but still the data does not get sent to the api.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api

Answer (score 0):

change ur code as follows..install axios first

```
submit = () => {
   
 const url='http://10.0.0.2:8000/api/mdlApp/' 
    
    let collection = {
     email: this.state.email,
     pwd: this.state.pwd
    };
    
    axios.post(`${url}`, collection, {
    
    headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
    }
    } ).then(res => {
    console.log(res.data)
    }))
    }
```

Comment: It is still not working even though the API is functioning. What could possibly be wrong?