# There is no options of dev settings in developer menu of react native on my android device

Tags: react-native, api, localhost, expo

I want to connect to localhost API on my laptop from my react native application on my android device. I saw this reply here

[React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)

There it is suggested to shake the device, this will open developers menu and then click on dev settings. However when I shake the device and open the developers menu there is no dev settings option. I am attaching the screen shot of developers menu.[image: Screen shot of developers menu]

what is happening here ? moreover is there any other way to connect my device to localhost api on my laptop??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this option is only available when using react-native-cli and not expo -cli.

i am now using ngrok to connect rest api in my laptop to my react native expo app in mobile device