# I want to call my local API with this 'http://localhost:8080/profile?id=1' but its error like TypeError : Network request failed

Tags: reactjs, native

I want to call my local API with this 'http://localhost:8080/profile?id=1' but its error like TypeError : Network request failed.

**This is my code and i want to call my local API**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import styles from '../style/Event.style';

const URL = "http://localhost:8080/profile?id=1"
const Event = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(URL)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.data))
      .catch((error) => alert(error))
  })
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <Text>{item.name}</Text>
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      />
      <Text>{data.name}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Event;
```

**Anyone know how can i do to make a call with local API?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)

Comment: http://10.0.2.2 i use this to and not happen