# Android Emulator can't reach local docker https URL

Tags: android, react-native, docker, https, dns

I'm working on a ReactNative application with webviews. I set up a docker with my apache server / API with an SSL certificate. On iOS there is no problem all requests are good and I can display my webview in my app or in safari, but on Android nothing. When I search for the URL on my browser it's supposed to show me the page but there is an error "The site can't be reached. Check if there is a typo in %URL. DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

I don't know what to do and if there is more information I can give you to understand the problem. Do you have any idea?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: What is the IP/URL you use for accessing the Apache server? You can try to disable secure DNS in the emulator to use your local DNS in case you don't use an IP address.

Comment: It has been a long time ago that I've worked with this but I remember it had something to do with the port forwarding in the emulator settings, but I would be wrong tho! Maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/43277765/6822962