# How to communicate django api with frontend react native?

Tags: python, django, react-native, android-studio

I have a django application and I have a react native app. I am running the android emulator from android studio.

And now I try to connect the backend with the frontend. I studied the example from:  `https://reactnative.dev/docs/network`

And the example url: [https://reactnative.dev/movies.json'](https://reactnative.dev/movies.json%27) works.

I run the native-react app on port: http://192.168.1.69:19000/
And I run the backend on port: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/

But now I try to connect with my own localhost data. So this is my component:

```
import { ActivityIndicator, FlatList, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            data: [],
            isLoading: true,
        };
    }

        async getMovies() {
        try {
            const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/", {
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                },
            });
            const json = await response.json();
            this.setState({ data: json.movies });
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        } finally {
            this.setState({ isLoading: false });
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getMovies();
    }

    render() {
        const { data, isLoading } = this.state;

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24 }}>
                {isLoading ? (
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                ) : (
                    <FlatList
                        data={data}
                        keyExtractor={({ id }, index) => id}
                        renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
                    />
                )}
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

this is the data from postman:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Husband",
        "description": "Very nice wife cocks the man",
        "no_of_ratings": 1,
        "avg_rating": 5.0
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Nice movie",
        "description": "Description ah, niceNICE",
        "no_of_ratings": 0,
        "avg_rating": 0
    }
]
```

But if I try to run this example. I get this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

Question: how to make a connection from native react witht the backend?

Oke, I installed:django.cors.headers and in settings I did all the configuration.

So in django I have this:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:3000",
]
```

and in react native I have this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/animalGroups/group/", {
            method: "GET",
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((jsonres) => setAnimalGroup(jsonres))
            .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }, []);
```

and the native react app is running on:

```
› Opening exp://192.168.1.69:19000 on MY_ANDROID
```

So but I still get this error:

```
Network request failed
at node_modules\whatwg-fetch\dist\fetch.umd.js:null in setTimeout$argument_0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)

Comment: I tried: http://10.0.2.2:3000/api/movies/ and http://10.0.2.2:8080/api/movies/. But still gettting the error can't fetch data

Comment: use your system's IpAdress as base url

Comment: @Ragnar. What exactly do you mean?  Used by react-native is: Metro waiting on exp://192.168.1.69:19000 and in the browser I am using: localhost:19006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the steps to Set CORS and call your application endpoint directly.

1.) Set the backend endpoint to accept and display data from incoming requests.
i.) first do something like this pip install : `pip install django-cors-headers`
ii.) in your `settings.py` file, add the following code snippet to your file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    
             ...
    
             'corsheaders',
    
            ...
    
            ]
```

iii.) add CORS middleware to django file

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  ...
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', //<== Add this
    ]
```

iv.) add `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True` to settings.py

v.) Endpoint is now accessible to every app.

2.) Make your fetch to be something like this

```
getMovies = async () => {
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/';

    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        setTransaction_details(responseJson);
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

Comment: @Lucas.Thank you for you contribution. I waas a couple of days under wool. But If it works I let you know.

Comment: @Lucas.updated the post

Answer (score 0):

if this isn't too late, use the IP your React native app opens to connect to your Django api.

use: `192.168.1.69:` for your allowed host in stettings.py

also, add the following to setting.py directly under the allowed host settings.

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://192.168.1.69:19000',
]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW = True
CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True
```

then your fetch in react native should be: `"http://192.168.1.69:8000/api/movies/"`
not:`'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/movies/'`

note that this is just an example. the IP you use should be the one your React native runs on. so start your React native app, and then copy the IP it gives you to the areas I mentioned above.

best of luck