# TypeError: Network request failed, when fetching API request

Tags: react-native, syntax, fetch-api, general-network-error

I am encountering an error when fetching a locally deployed API(Firebase). Pasting the API link in the web browser works, but not in my react-native app. When calling the function, it returns a Network Request Failed Error, when I check in the Debug, there is no specific Error. Here is the fetch function:

```
const SignInPress = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'http://127.0.0.1/:5001/freelance-services-api-a0277/us-central1/app/api/freelancers',
        {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-ORIGIN': '*',
          },
        },
      );
      const json = await response.json();
      return json;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }};
```

I have tried different methods such as changing the IP address and modifying the Android.xml file so that it accepts http links, but the error still exists.

Comment: just to be sure is your wifi or cellular data on?

Comment: @vatsalsoni yes the wifi is on

Answer (score 0):

To do a request to your local machine, you must to use your local IP, after you need to update your Android and iOS configurations.

You can see this link:
[Connecting React Native to localhost](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/connecting-react-native-to-localhost-65e7ddf43d02)

There is also an issue like that about fetch local data on Android: [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)