# TypeError: Network request failed while working on react native (Js)

Tags: javascript, react-native, phpmyadmin, typeerror

I working on React-native and testing my app on expo(android phone), trying to save data in phpmyadmin that user will input in , I am getting this error. `[TypeError: Network request failed]`
code:

```
const handleSaveMobileNumber = async () => {
    if (mobileNumber.length === 11 && /^\d+$/.test(mobileNumber)) {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost/phpmyadmin:3306/saveMobileNumber', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ mobileNumber }),
      });
      const result = await response.text();
      Alert.alert(result);
      navigation.navigate('Home');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error saving mobile number:', error);
    }} else
  {Alert.alert('Please enter a valid 11-digit mobile number.');
  }};
```

I tried changing port number but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)