# Problems to connect my apk expo with my local server

Tags: android, node.js, react-native, express, expo

my app doesn't connect with my local server, and idk why. When I was coding my app and I tested it with expo go, it was great. But when I converted it in apk and I install it in my phone, It didn't connect to the local server as when I used expo go, do you have the solution?

I was looking my code but I didn't find any wrong, so I dont know what can I do. You can see my repositories, it is a short project. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Android Fetch failing on connection to local API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api)

Comment: Please do not link to repos in your question, as they can change. Always post a [mcve]