# Localhost API request not working in React Native Expo

Tags: react-native, express, expo

I made a Express API and while testing it with postman it work fine but while using it in react native it log network error but i check CORS is enable in my API but still it does not connect to my API i also try to use AXIOS try async await and even change my URL to http:{ipAddress}:8000/api/v1 but none of them is working.

```js
const register = () => {
    const { name, email, password, confirmPassword } = formData;
    const trimmedName = name.trim();
    if (trimmedName === "") {
      alert("Name can not be empty.");
      return;
    }

    const emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;
    if (!emailRegex.test(email)) {
      alert("Invalid email format.");
      return;
    }

    if (
      password !== confirmPassword ||
      password === "" ||
      confirmPassword === ""
    ) {
      alert("Password does not match.");
      return;
    }

    fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/register", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        name: trimmedName,
        email,
        password,
      }),
    })
      .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        setFormData({
          name: null,
          email: null,
          password: null,
          confirmPassword: null,
        });
        console.log(data);
        alert(data.message);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("There was an error!", error);
        alert(error.message || "Internal server error.");
      });
  };
```

Comment: I guess your Express API is on a desktop OS and react native is in a VM ? you may refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33704130/react-native-android-fetch-failing-on-connection-to-local-api